# How to define several functions at once that differ only by name (without using macros)?

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a simple math vector class that basically just wraps a `double` array.

Now I want to be able to element-wise apply standard math functions on this vector. E.g. my `sqrt()` implementation looks like this:

```
MyVector sqrt(MyVector x) // side note: makes a copy of the input vector
{
    for (double& d : x)
        d = std::sqrt(d);
    return x;
}
```

This works fine. The issue I'm facing is, that I want my vector to be usable with basically all functions in `<cmath>` that have this signature: `double (*)(double)`.

Note that the implementation of these functions would be *identical* to the one of `sqrt()`. The only difference is the function name.

My current solution is a macro:

```
#define DEFINE(function) \
MyVector function(MyVector x) \
{ \
    for (double& d : x) \
        d = std::function(d); \
    return x; \
}

DEFINE(sqrt)
DEFINE(exp)
DEFINE(sin)
DEFINE(cos)
.
.
.
```

Is there any non-macro way?

### Update

I want these to be free functions to allow generic template code without having to care if the type is a vector or built in.

Comment: Are these member functions?

Comment: Since there is no way to introduce a **name** in C++ rather than writing a macro, you have to use macro on some level.

Comment: @NathanOliver No, I would like to have free functions to allow the very same syntax for my vector as for built in types.

Comment: Use `std::for_each(begin(vec), end(vec), fn)` instead?

Comment: Can't help with that then.  If you're willing to use a member function you can make an `apply` function and then you would just pass a lambda to it.  It would look like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf9c2a37aef69222)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to use a macro to introduce a name, but you can cut down on how long it is

```
constexpr auto make_op(double(*op)(double))
{
    return [op](MyVector x) 
    { 
        std::transform(std::begin(x), std::end(x), std::begin(x), op); 
        return x; 
    };
}

#define DEFINE(op) constexpr auto op = make_op(std::op);

DEFINE(sqrt)
DEFINE(exp)
DEFINE(sin)
DEFINE(cos)
```

Note that you may run into issues of redefining those symbols in `::`, so it's best to wrap this in a namespace.

[See it live!](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b18ed730232838d5)